# CORS issue: Firefox extension making AJAX request

Tags: ajax, firefox-addon, cors

I am creating an extension for Firefox. Before I had this issue issue on Chrome, but fixed it by providing this in in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

Now I am trying to provide this in `manifest.json` for Firefox Extension, but still receiving CORS error when I try make AJAX request. How should I provide this?

Tried all possible way, no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jpm then you have to do this, to `package.json` add:

```
  "permissions": {
     "cross-domain-content": ["https://data.com"]
  }
```

Comment: Tried this, no luck :(

Comment: @Aktau-Seattle that is very weird, did you put the proper domain names in the array? This has to work.

Comment: would you please look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031336/small-firefox-add-on-installed-but-not-run